# I can't read the Xml data by VBA(selectsinglenode but is nothing)

Tags: html, excel, xml, vba, http

here is the Xml data

```xml
        <NewZipCdListResponse>
          <cmmMsgHeader>
            <requestMsgId/>
            <responseMsgId/>
            <responseTime>20220526:085103847</responseTime>
            <successYN>Y</successYN>
            <returnCode>00</returnCode>
            <errMsg/>
            <totalCount>3</totalCount>
            <countPerPage>1</countPerPage>
            <totalPage>3</totalPage>
            <currentPage>1</currentPage>
          </cmmMsgHeader>
          <newZipCdList>
            <zipNo>11033</zipNo>
            <address>경기도 연천군 전곡읍 은전로 80 (전곡리, 연천전곡새마을금고)</address>
            <rangeKind/>
            </newZipCdList>
        </NewZipCdListResponse>
```

I wanna get it to my excel. But i don't know why I cannot do that.

maybe the error is in sentence, "set nodecell1 = objXml.select/.....".
Because nodecell have notthing and I don't know the reason.

here is part of my code.

```
Sub tracker()

Dim strURL As String
Dim strResult As String
Dim i As Long
Dim objHttp As New WinHttpRequest
Dim oldTime As Single

    For i = 2 To Range("a60000").End(xlUp).Row
        
    strURL = "http://openapi.epost.go.kr/postal/retrieveNewZipCdService/retrieveNewZipCdService/getNewZipCdList?ServiceKey=_____&srchwrd=" & Range("a" & i)
    
    objHttp.Open "GET", strURL, False
    objHttp.Send


If objHttp.Status = 200 Then '성공했을 경우(if success)
strResult = objHttp.ResponseText

'XML로 연결(contect XML)
Dim objXml As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set objXml = New DOMDocument60
objXml.LoadXML (strResult)

'노드 연결(contect node)
Dim nodeCell1 As IXMLDOMNode
Dim nodeCell2 As IXMLDOMNode
Set nodeCell1 = objXml.SelectSingleNode("/NewZipCdListResponse/newZipCdList/zipNo")
Set nodeCell2 = objXml.SelectSingleNode("/NewZipCdListResponse/newZipCdList/address")

'엑셀에 값 반영(input it to excel)
Cells(i, 2).Value = nodeCell1.Text
Cells(i, 3).Value = nodeCell2.Text

Else
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample value, e.g. the content of cell `A2` ?

Comment: Does the code inside `If objHttp.Status = 200 Then` actually run?

Comment: to Spectral : that is the part of address(eg : "경기도 연천군 전곡읍 은전로 80"  the korean data)

Comment: to TW sure that do well

Comment: I was afraid of that - unfortunately, my VBA IDE only supports Latin characters, so I can't be of any help.

Comment: is there any worng part when you just ckeck up?

Comment: Your code works fine for me if I load your posted XML from a worksheet cell.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```vb
Sub tracker()

    Dim objXml As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim nodeCell1 As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim nodeCell2 As IXMLDOMNode
    
    Set objXml = New DOMDocument60
    objXml.LoadXML Range("A1").Value 'loading XML from worksheet cell for testing
    
    Set nodeCell1 = objXml.SelectSingleNode("/NewZipCdListResponse/newZipCdList/zipNo")
    Set nodeCell2 = objXml.SelectSingleNode("/NewZipCdListResponse/newZipCdList/address")
    
    Range("B1").Value = nodeCell1.Text
    Range("C1").Value = nodeCell2.Text
    
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]